# An NSArrayController changes its selection : what is the best way to catch this event?

Tags: macos, cocoa, model-view-controller, nsarraycontroller

One can put an observer on the `selectedIndex` method of `NSArrayController`. This method has some drawbacks I think :

- what will happen when the `arrangedObjects` is rearranged ? I admit this is not a very important problem
- if we ask the observer to remember the old value of `selectedIndex`, it doesn't work. It is known but I cannot find again the link.

Why doesn't NSArrayController have a delegate ?
Is there another way to achieve what I want to do : launching some methods when the selection changes ?

Comment: I don't have a `TableView` in my interface...

Comment: How is the selection change triggered? Have you considered KVO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe `selection` key of the `NSArrayController` (it is inherited from `NSObjectController`).

It will return either `NSMultipleValuesMarker` (when many objects are selected), `NSNoSelectionMarker` (when nothing is selected), or a proxy representing the selected object which can then be queried for the original object value through `self` key.

It will not change if rearranging objects did not actually change the selection.

You can also observe `selectedObjects`; in that case you won't need to deal with markers.

Comment: Thanks! Can you be more precise on "Observe selection key of the NSArrayController"? Can you pur some code?

Comment: @Colas This is done the same way you would observe `selectedIndex` — by calling `[arrayController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selection" ...]` and implementing `observeValueForKeyPath:...`. It is an ordinary property of `NSArrayController`, you probably missed it from the docs because it is inherited from superclass.

Comment: Do you think creating a `NSTableView` (that will not be displayed) and using the delegate methods can be better?

Comment: @Colas `NSTableView` observes `selectionIndexes` and will give you the same rearrange issue, besides, that would be a terrible waste of resources. Observing `selection`/`selectedObjects` is the proper, documented way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Providing hamstergene's excellent solution, in Swift 4.

In `viewDidLoad`, observe the key path.

```
arrayController.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "selectedObjects", options: .new, context: nil)
```

In the view controller,

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    guard let keyPath = keyPath else { return }

    switch keyPath {

    case "selectedObjects":
        // arrayController.selectedObjects has changed

    default:
        break
    }
}
```